# How do you convert an array of text labels into vectors for input into a CNN in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I have a set of data that is a bunch of pictures organized into folders like so:

```
/animals
    /dogs
    /cats
    /snakes
    /pandas
```

etc, there are 10 different categories

I have an array called `trainingImages[]` which contains all my preprocessed data (grayscale, 32x32)

I have an array called `trainingLabels[]` which contains all the labels, they match indeces with trainingImages[]. So trainingImages[1] is a preprocessed dog, and trainingLabels[1] is the string 'dog'

I then used sklearns `train_test_split()` like so:

```
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(trainingImages, trainingLabels, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

At this point trainX and trainY have shapes: `(1095, 32, 32, 1) (1095, 20, 2)` respectively

I know I now have to convert `trainY` into one-hot vectors. I've tried using `LabelBinarizer` and `to_categorical`, but I still have shape issues:

```
lb = LabelBinarizer().fit(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)
trainY = lb.transform(trainY)

testY = keras.utils.to_categorical(testY)
trainY = keras.utils.to_categorical(trainY)
```

But I get the `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1095, 20, 2)` error when I input it into my `Sequential` model, which tells me the shape is wrong on input.

How would I properly prepare this data?

EDIT:

Code:

```
inputWidth = 32
inputHeight = 32
inputDepth = 1

batchSize = 32
inputShape = (inputHeight, inputWidth, inputDepth)

trainDataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. /255, shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
testDataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. /255)

trainingSet = trainDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(args.dataset,
    target_size=(32, 32), batch_size=batchSize, class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode='grayscale')
testingSet = testDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(args.dataset,
    target_size=(32, 32), batch_size=batchSize, class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode='grayscale')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same", input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(500))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(trainingClasses))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit_generator(trainingSet, steps_per_epoch=80, epochs=20,
    validation_data=testingSet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Keras ImageDataGenerator. The generator takes all folders in a root directory and creates categories for each of them. All files in each categorical folder are automatically assigned to the category of their parent folder. Splitting between test and training set can then easily be done by hand in 2 minutes.

```
batch_size = 32
# Noise data by zooming, rotating and flipping for more diverse training

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('folder/of/training/root/directory',
                                                 target_size=input_size,
                                                 batch_size=batch_size,
                                                 class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('folder/of/test/root/directory',
                                            target_size=input_size,
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            class_mode='categorical')


# Train the CNN on catigories defined by the folder structure
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=8000/batch_size,
                         epochs=90,
                         validation_data=test_set,
                         validation_steps=2000/batch_size,
                         workers=12)
```

You can get the one hot encoded catigories by issuing:

```
print("The model class indices are:", training_set.class_indices)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! When following this method, I get `StopIteration: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,32,3) into shape (32,32,1,3)` 

Do I need to manually create a dimension in my input matrix that holds the batches?

Comment: @A_toaster Could you provide the context where the error occurs and share the code of your architecture?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it! I think I was calling `trainDataGenerator.flow` instead of `testDataGenerator.flow`

Thanks for your help! `ImageDataGenerator` seems to be the way to go when running from a directory!

Comment: @A_toaster Glad I could help you.